# Prove a beta-function-related formula, using induction

Tags: real-analysis, integration, induction, improper-integrals

Problem source: problem 18, "Introduction to Real Analysis", William F. Trench, Trinity University. [Here is the book](https://digitalcommons.trinity.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1006&context=mono)

> Prove that $$\int_0^1 {y^n}(1-y)^r dy = {\frac{n!}{(r + 1)(r + 2) \dots (r + n + 1)}}$$ if $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $r > -1$

I know that $$\int_0^1 y^a(1-y)^b dy = B(a + 1, b + 1) = \frac{a! b!}{(a + b + 1)!}$$ with $a! = \Gamma(a + 1)$ (or the factorial equivalent $a! = \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^a k}$. However, using the Beta function right away could be a little too overboard, so instead I want to solve the problem the "possibly intended" way. Define $f(n) = \displaystyle{\int_0^1 y^n(1-y)^r dy}$, we need to prove that $f(n) = \frac{n!}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n + 1} (r + k)}}$

Since $n$ is a nonnegative integer, we begin with the base case $n = 0$:

$$
f(0) = \int_0^1 (1-y)^r dy \stackrel{t = 1  - y, dt = -dy}{======} \int_1^0 t^r(-dt) \\ = \int_0^1 t^r dt = \left. \frac{t^{r + 1}}{r + 1} \right|_0^1 = \frac{1}{r + 1} - \frac{0}{r + 1} = \frac{1}{r + 1} = \frac{0!}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{0+1} k}}
$$

which means the statement is true with $n = 0$. Now, for some integer $n > 0$, assume the statement holds, which means $f(n) = \displaystyle{\int_0^1 y^n(1-y)^r dy} = \frac{n!}{(r + 1)(r + 2) \dots (r + n + 1)}$. We then have:

$$
f(n + 1) = \displaystyle{\int_0^1 y^{n + 1} (1-y)^r dy} = \displaystyle{\int_0^1 y \cdot y^{n} (1-y)^r dy}
$$

or at least that was what I wanted, before I get stuck in this. I tried integration by parts:
$$
u = y, u' = y' \\
v' = y^n(1-y)^r,  v = ?
$$

I can't seem to think of anything else, can you help me?

P/S: can anyone help me on how to make an extremely long equal sign with symbols on top in MathJax Latex (the type used on this site)?

Comment: A comment on notation: I feel like rather than using some unholy long equals sign, the standard way to write something like this would be to either (1) not mention the change of variables since it's a fairly trivial substitution, (2) write the chain of equalities using multiple (aligned) lines and write the change of variables to the right of the relevant equality/derivation-step, or (3) explain after the fact "where the second equality is due to the substitution $t=1-y$". You can probably get away with approach (1) in this case.

Comment: The verb is "prove", not proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mostly have the right idea, but it's better to define
$$f(n,r) = \int_0^1 y^n(1-y)^rdy$$
since the inductive step will actually change $r$.

Now we can compute $f(n,r)$ using integration by parts with $u = y^n$ and $v = -\frac{1}{r+1}(1-y)^{r+1}$. Note that $uv$ vanishes at $0$ and $1$ whenever $n>0$ and $r>-1$, so there are no boundary terms. Thus
$$f(n,r) = \int_0^1 uv' = -\int_0^1 u'v = -\int_0^1 (ny^{n-1})\left(-\frac{1}{r+1}(1-y)^{r+1}\right) = \frac{n}{r+1}f(n-1,r+1).$$
From here it should be easy to inductively prove the stated formula.

Comment: >the inductive step will actually change $r$
\\ 
yeah this is my gripe for it. Can you continue where you left off? I know how the idea works now, but I still can't wrap my head around everything

Comment: @MinhĐứcHoàng what are you confused about? I already showed how to derive the recursion for $f(n,r)$, all you need to do is show that the formula you're asked to prove satisfies the same recursion.